# Storing the results of a nested for-loop into a matrix in R

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix, vector

I am trying to create a matrix in which each row represents the data from a vector obtained through a for loop. My code below results in only one number in the final matrix when it is supposed to have 5 rows with 60 columns. Each gene_state vector should be of length 60, and the aim is to piece 5 of them together in a matrix as N = 5.

```
set.seed(1)
N <- 5
t <- 60
myMatrix <- matrix(0, nrow=N, ncol=t)
for(i in 1:N){
  gene_state <- 1
  for(j in 1:t){
    randomNum <- runif(1)  #runif(1) randomly generates a number between 0 and 1
    if(gene_state == 1){     # if the gene_state is at 1 
      if(randomNum < 0.1){   # AND if the random number generated is less than 0.1
        gene_state <- 2    # switch the state to 2
      } else {     
        gene_state <- 1    # otherwise keep the state at 1
      }
    } else {           # if the gene_state is at 2
      if(randomNum < 0.25){  # and if the random number is less than 0.25
        gene_state <- 1    # switch the state to 1
      }else{
        gene_state <- 2  # otherwise keep the state at 2
      }
    }
    myMatrix[i,j] <- gene_state
  }
}
```

Comment: I get a 5x60 matrix

Comment: @PaulR Please, let me know what your reasoning is to remove the `for-loop` tag from this question.

Comment: @UweBlock: it didn't seem to be a particularly useful tag in this context - I felt that adding the missing `r` tag was probably quite important, the `matrix` and `vector` tags were borderline, so I left them in, but the `for-loop` tag seems useless. That's just my opinion though - feel free to add it back in if you think it has some value,

Comment: @PaulR Many novice `R` users are not aware that a lot of functions in `R` are efficiently vectorized or vectorizable. So, the `for-loop` tag on `R` questions is quite a good indicator.

Comment: Fair enough - please go ahead and add the tag back in again.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the code does what it is intended for. I cut all the comments out and rearranged the last line

```
N <- 5
t <- 60
myMatrix <- matrix(0, nrow=N, ncol=t)
for(i in 1:N){
    gene_state <- 1
    for(j in 1:t){
        randomNum <- runif(1)
        if(gene_state == 1){
            if(randomNum < 0.1){
                gene_state <- 2
            } else {     
                gene_state <- 1
            }
        } else {
            if(randomNum < 0.25){
                gene_state <- 1
            }else{
                gene_state <- 2
            }
        }
        myMatrix[i,j] <- gene_state
    }}
```

which results in the the 5 x 60 matrix.

```
dim(myMatrix)
[1]  5 60
```

Comment: Thank you! It works now, not sure why it was giving me something different the other day...